# Is there an exclusive OR 'XOR' in XPath?

Tags: xslt, xpath

Is there an exclusive OR 'XOR'  in XPath1.0 ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
x and not(y)   or   y and not(x)
```

**Always try to avoid the `!=` operator**, because it has an unexpected meaning/behavior when one or both of its arguments are node-sets.

**In XSLT 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 one can write this as a function** and then use just the function in any XPath expression. Below is an XSLT 2.0 function definition for `xor` and a small example of using this function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="my:f">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "for $x in (true(), false()),
       $y in (true(), false())
     return
       ('xor(', $x, ',', $y,') = ', f:xor($x, $y), '&#xA;')
  "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="f:xor">
  <xsl:param name="pX" as="xs:boolean"/>
  <xsl:param name="pY" as="xs:boolean"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
   "$pX and not($pY)   or   $pY and not($pX)"/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 xor( true , true ) =  false
 xor( true , false ) =  true 
 xor( false , true ) =  true 
 xor( false , false ) =  false
```

Comment: +1 good example of XPath 2.0 features, and of a demo that thoroughly demonstrates the functionality. (And avoiding tricky existential comparisons.)

Answer (score 3):

No but you can emulate it:

```
(a or b) and (a != b)
```

Comment: It doesn't exist neither in XPath 2.0.

Comment: @Christophe: This works if we assume that `a` and `b` are single boolean values. If either one is a nodeset, watch out for existential comparisons. A safer form would be `(a or b) and not(a and b)`.

Comment: @LarsH You're right, it's safer. Nevertheless, practically, logical operations seldom occur on node-sets with multiple nodes so I provided the more straightforward expression for this purpose.

Comment: I think logical operations are seldom *intended* to occur on node-sets with multiple nodes. When beginners are learning, in my experience it's pretty common to select multiple nodes without realizing it. (I did it yesterday, and I've been using XSLT for about 10 years!) When that happens, the results can be baffling, especially to someone who is still learning the ropes. Safer coding is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

`number($boolean_var)` converts `true()` to `1` and `false()` to `0`. (Note that `true` alone addresses a node!!)

`boolean($numeric_var)` converts `1` to `true()` and `0` to `false()`.

Therefore, XOR can be accomplished by:

`boolean((number($v1) + number($v2) + number($v3)) mod 2)`

i.e. least-significant-bit addition using the `mod 2` operator. Yes, XPATH is cumbersome.