# Why can't I scrape numbers over 999,999? (XPaths in Python)

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the number of travelers to foreign countries from a site (link in code). For some reason when I actually get the data displayed it ignores any number over 999,999. Maybe someone can spot what I'm missing here.

```
    import requests
    from lxml import html
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    import re

    r = requests.get('http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/ST.INT.ARVL/countries/1W     page=4&order=wbapi_data_value_2014%20wbapi_data_value%20wbapi_data_value-  last&sort=asc&display=default')
    data = html.fromstring(r.text)

    Data1995 = []
    Data_1995 = data.xpath("//tbody/tr[td]/td[2]/text()")

    for i in Data_1995:
        i = i.encode('ascii','ignore').strip()
        i = re.sub('[()]', '', i)  # removing ()
        Data1995.append(i)

    Data1995
```

Comment: Because those larger numbers are in another element. `<span class="bignum">1,750,000</span>`

Comment: Does that mean that it won't be possible for me to get all of the numbers with one Xpath?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with XPath, but it would seem so

Comment: You can use an or in your xpath

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes

Comment: @PadraicCunningham

Thank you for your help! Got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
Data1995 = []

for elem in data.xpath("//tbody/tr[td]/td[2]"):
    i = elem.xpath("string(.)")
    i = i.encode('ascii','ignore').strip()
    i = re.sub('[()]', '', i)  # removing ()
    Data1995.append(i)
```

Omitting the `text()` step from the XPath expression will return the `td` elements. Then `elem.xpath("string(.)")` extracts the [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) of each `td` element. For [element nodes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes), the string value "is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order."

I recommend this technique in general as it is much more robust. Take the following `td` element, for example:

```
<td>A <i>simple</i> example</td>
```

Selecting `td/text()` will return two text nodes containing `A` and `example`. Typically, this is not what you want. The approach I described returns `A simple example`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting together the comments from **cricket_007** and **Padraic Cunningham** 
You may try the following xpath:

```
//tbody/tr[td]/td[2][not(span)]/text() | 
//tbody/tr[td]/td[2]/span/text()
```

Comment: I figured it out, but this is very close to what I got. Thank you for the suggestion!