# Get two sets of elements with XPath

Tags: javascript, xpath

Say I have the XPath expressions `//*[@class="red"]/a` and `//*[@class="blue"]`. How do I get both results in a single XPath expression? This is an OR operation.

Comment: possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes)

Comment: Is second XPath correct or it should be `//*[@class="blue"]/a`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of below options if you want your XPath to fetch nodes with `class="blue"` OR `class="red"`:

```
//*[@class=("blue", "red")]/a #  XPath 2.0
//*[@class="blue" or @class="red"]/a
```

In case you need both node with `class="blue"` and child of node with `class="red"`:

```
//*[@class="blue"] | //*[@class="red"]/a
```

Comment: Note that the syntax `[@class=("blue", "red")]` is XPath 2.0. The other expressions will all work with XPath 1.0.

Comment: In my system I have xpath 1.0, so I couldn't use the way you are telling here, can you let me know how would I move to xpath 2.0?

Comment: @Rajagopalan , XPath is not something you can install on your system - it's just a syntax that can or cannot be supported by the tool you uses

Comment: Ah okay. What do you mean by tool here ? Which tool? Selenium is the tool?

Comment: @Melab, Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in case it solved your issue

Comment: @Rajagopalan , yeap. Selenium is the tool that supports (currently) XPath 1.0 only

Comment: Can you tell me what other tool supports xpath 2.0?

Comment: For instance, XSLT 2.0 supports XPath 2.0. But if you're looking for web-scraping tool - AFAIK none of them supports XPath 2.0 or XPath 3.0 versions...

Comment: Hi thank you very much! Since you haven't pinged my name in the comment I couldn't see the comment immediately. Thank you much for clearing the doubts.