# ruby, assign the var that is not nill

Tags: ruby

I have in the html the location variable sometimes is used with a class called "result-hood" sometimes is used with another class called "nearby"

```
    location = result.search('span.result-hood').text[2..-2]
    location2 = result.search('span.nearby').text[2..-2]
```

so if one of the above classes is not used the result is nill, my question is how to get always the one that is not nill, I was thinking about the ternary operator "?" , but don't know how to use it.
Thanks,

Comment: To clarify, would it ever have _both_ classes, or is it exclusively one or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `||` ("or") operator:

```
    location || location2
```

It returns the left side if that is not nil or false, and otherwise it returns the right side.

Answer (score 3):

`CSS` supports logical `or` operations using a comma as the delimiter, so your selector can just be:

```
location = result.search('span.result-hood,span.nearby').text[2..-2]
```

`XPath` also supports [logical `or` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes#5351353) itself, the equivalent `XPath` would look like

```
location = result.search('//span[@class="result-hood"]|//span[@class="nearby"]').text[2..-2]
```

Comment: It does not work        C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4-x64-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/css/parser_extras.rb:87:in `on_error': unexpected '|' after '[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x000000000781bbc0 @type=:CONDITIONAL_SELECTOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x000000000781be40 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["span"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x000000000781bcd8 @type=:CLASS_CONDITION, @value=["result-hood"]>]>]' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)

Comment: I didn’t know `nokogiri` is as stupid. `result.xpath('//span[@class="result-hood"] | //span[@class="nearby"]')` then.

Comment: @mudasobwa it is not that `nokogiri` is stupid it is that you answered the question using a mutation of `css` and `xpath` syntax and nokogiri saw it as css. For `css` the pattern would be `'span.result-hood,span.nearby'` because comma is `CSS`'s logical or. Please feel free to append this to your answer as it is a better choice than the "correct" answer in this case. [Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/NokogiriPathSearching)

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator in ruby:

```
loc = location.nil? ? location2 : location
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Technically true, but if it's not possible or likely that `location` would be literal `false` then `location || location2` is better.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're looking for one or the other you can reduce this code to:

```
location = result.search('span.result-hood').text[2..-2]
   || result.search('span.nearby').text[2..-2]
```

Where that `search` operation could be fairly expensive, so why run it twice when you might need to run it only once. Now that you've minimized it like this you can take it a step further:

```
location = %w[ span.result-hood span.nearby ].map do |selector|
  result.search(selector).text[2..-2]
end.compact.first
```

This looks a little complicated but what it does is convert each selector into the text extracted from `result.search(...).text[2..-2]` and then take the first non-`nil` value.

That technically computes all possible bits of text before extracting, so you can make it "lazy" and evaluate each one in sequence instead, stopping at the first match:

```
location = %w[ span.result-hood span.nearby ].lazy.map do |selector|
  result.search(selector).text[2..-2]
end.select(&:itself).first
```

The nice thing about this approach is you can clean it up a little by declaring a constant in advance:

```
LOCATIONS = %w[ span.result-hood span.nearby ]
```

Then later you have more minimal code like this that will automatically accommodate any changes made to that array both in terms of precedence and addition of others:

```
location = LOCATIONS.lazy.map do |selector|
  result.search(selector).text[2..-2]
end.select(&:itself).first
```

Comment: while `lazy` is definitely extremely cool. In this case it has no impact if "span.result-hood" is `nil` as this will still have to be evaluated in `select`. Additionally `select(&:itself).first` is equivalent to `detect(&:itself)`

Comment: `detect(&:itself)` is a distinct improvement, yeah.