# Selenium wait until one of two elements are visible

Tags: c#, selenium

How could I wait until one of two elements is visible? I'm currently using ExpectedConditions - example of usage is,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

IWebElement waitresponse = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("example')]")));
```

but that is only relevant to one element, how can I add a OR?

Attempted example,

```
IWebElement waitresponse = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("example')]") || (By.XPath("Example2")));
```

However no luck using

```
||
```

maybe my syntax is wrong?

Comment: This might be a way of accomplishing it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the line as below

```
IWebElement waitresponse = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("xpath1|xpath2")));
```

Comment: Operator | cannot be applied to operands of  type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: Updated the answer.Here is the sample `By.Xpath("//button[.='Cancel']|//button[.='Close']")`.

Answer (score -1):

```
driver= webdriver.Firefox()

def wait():
enter code here
if len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('whatever')) == 1:

   do whatever you have to do
else:
time.sleep(5)
wait()
```

Comment: The OP want to check for if either of the elements visible. I don't prefer `len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('whatever'))` as there may be other elements with same tag already present on the page, which will give the false positive.

Comment: its not what OP asked