# How to cancel specific wait in Selenium?

Tags: typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, async-await

Suppose I'm need to wait for some result, but there also can appear another results, so in this case I use 2 wait(), but problem is what I can't cancel one wait() if after execution one of them was appeared

Example:

```
async waitForAction(): Promise<any> {
  try{
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(button)); // 1st wait
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(unexpectedErr)); // 2nd wait

    await driver.findElement(button).click()

   // how to cancel 2nd wait if 1st appeared 

  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't cancel a wait. One solution would be to combine the `button` and `unexpectedErr` locators using an OR operator. Since we don't have the actual locators, I'll give you an example. Let's say `button` looks like

```
<button id="submit">
```

The CSS selector for that would be `#submit`. Let's say that `unexpectedErr` looks like

```
<div class="error">...</div>
```

The CSS selector for that would be `div.error`. The OR operator in CSS selector syntax is a comma `,` so the combined locator would look like.

```
#submit, div.error
```

So your method would look like

```
async waitForAction(): Promise<any> {
  try{
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(comboLocator)); // combo wait

    await driver.findElement(button).click()
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message)
  }
}
```

If you are using XPath, the OR operator* is a pipe character `|` so the combined locator would look like

```
//button[@id='submit'] | //div[@class='error']
```

*Pipe is not really an `OR` operator in XPath but it will do what you need here. See the XPath-related link in the references below.

**References**

[CSS selector reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)

[XPath "OR" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes)