# xpath contains text does not work with or operator

Tags: r, xpath

It seems that `contains(text(), 'TARGET_STRING')` works fine with `html_nodes` as well as the "or operator": "|", but it does not work together.

**Reproducible example:**

```
html <- "<a>a</a><p>abc</p>"

xp <- "//*[self::a|self::b]" # or operator works
xp2 <- "//*[contains(text(),'abc')]" # contains text works

# but it doesnt work together
xp3 <- "//*[self::a|contains(text(),'abc')]" 

html_nodes(x = read_html(html), xpath = xp)
html_nodes(x = read_html(html), xpath = xp2)

# this one fails
html_nodes(x = read_html(html), xpath = xp3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `|` with `or` to make it work:

```
//*[self::a or contains(text(),'abc')]
```

Comment: Oh wow could have tried that one. Do you have an idea why the "|" Operator does not work here? - P.S: I can accept in three minutes.

Comment: @Tlatwork , Note that `|` is not actually **OR** operator, but [**union set operator**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc30020_1251/html/xmlb/xmlb32.htm)

Comment: hah ok, if you read carefully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes (my source) it is also actually mentioned in the comments. Thank you!