# How to search for two elements with python web driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to do something so that if it cannot find this click on this.

I receive the TypeError: find_element_by_xpath() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given error when trying this

here is my code

```
import time

OOS = '//*[@id="notifyMe"]'
in_stock = '//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button'

for x in range(4):
    web = webdriver.Chrome()

    web.get('https://www.target.com/p/minecraft-bee-pillow-buddy/-/A-79337175')
    time.sleep(2)


    instock_button = web.find_element_by_xpath(OOS,in_stock ).click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPath OR operator for different nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes)

Comment: Nvm it works with or

Comment: Also look into driver.refresh() for reloading and webdriver waits for waiting for page loads. As well as using a try except in case it doesn't find the element.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
instock_button = web.find_element_by_xpath(OOS,in_stock ).click()
```

in_stock is an addition parameter to find_element_by_xpath() function. Remove the in_stock parameter and the exception will be gone away.

```
instock_button = web.find_element_by_xpath(OOS).click()
```

Comment: This does not answer my question though because if this element is not found i want it to click the other