# selecting html element by value or Id with selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two buttons("Continue registration") which are identical on two different pages
The first one is

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Continue registration">
```

and the second one is

```
<a id="confirm-button" href="#" onclick="onSubmit()" class="submit button">Continue registration</a>
```

I am looking for a way to target both of those elements with one Xpath

Currently I have a solution which works by mapping each of them to one element like this

```
    [SelectByXPath("//input[@value='Continue registration']")]
    public Button Continue { get; }

    [SelectByXPath("//*[@id='confirm-button']")]
    public Button ContinueWithId { get; }
```

I can also map  the first one by cssSelector and the second one by Id which works perfectly,
but ideally I would like to have something like this

```
    [SelectByXPath("//input[@value='Continue registration'] and *[@id='confirm-button']")]
    public Button Continue { get; }
```

which basically says find this element by value or by Id whichever is present on the page.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine two predicates try

```
"//*[@value='Continue registration' or @id='confirm-button']"
```

This will fetch both link and input node