# Get more Web elements types from FindElements() - Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

Hello guys can you please help me with my problem?
I have method where i check if several web objects are preset on page and if so then i click on them, it is working as intended however i like use only one FindElements() for it, is it possible?Can someone tell me how? Thanks

My elements :

```
 public static class Elements
    {                    
        public static string allow = "//button[@data-testid='allow']";
        public static string addToHomescreen="//button[@datatestid='addToHomeScreen']";
    }
```

My method inside for loop :

```
                var allow = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(Elements.allow));
                var addToHS = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(Elements.addToHomescreen));
                var newLike = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(Elements.like));

                if(allow.Count == 0 && addToHS.Count == 0 newLike.Count > 0)
                {
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Elements.like)).Click();
                }
                else if(allow.Count > 0)
                {
                    allow[0].Click();
                    Utils.Wait(1);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Elements.like)).Click();
                }
```

I want something like but cant get it done :

```
var allPopups= driver.FindElements(By.XPath(Elements.allow),By.XPath(Elements.addToHomescreen),);
```

I just need to FindElements() return more types of Elements but i cant figuer out syntax.
THanks

Comment: Instead you can try this :`var allPopups= driver.FindElements(By.XPath(Elements.allow + " | "+ Elements.addToHomescreen));` concat your xpaths with or logic.

Comment: @Eldar - thank you resolved, i was doing that but i was using +"||"+ instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in `xpath` itself, there is `or` keyword in `xpath`.

```
public static string allow_addToHomescreen = "//button[@data-testid='allow' or @datatestid='addToHomeScreen']";
```

also the below is equivalent too:-

```
public static string allow_addToHomescreen = "//button[@data-testid='allow' | @datatestid='addToHomeScreen']";
```

See more details [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes)